# How to request HTML from webpage using ajax?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I have this AJAX request:

```
        function getLinks(cn) {
            $.ajax({
                url: cn,
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                },
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                }
            });
        }

        var insecure_links = getLinks(url);
```

but whenever I run it, it always scans for `localhost:8080/google.com` instead of `google.com` (I just want the response to be the html of that page)

QUESTION: How do I modify this so that I can do a GET request to a certain page and receive the HTML of that page back?

If it helps, I'm doing this on Nodejs.

Comment: well, you would have to use a correct url first, but then you would have to get the owners of the external url to allow you to do this or scrape it using server-side code. `headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                }` on the client makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Okay, I see. I fixed the url, and the error code said basically what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be passing `cn` as `google.com` which may work in the browser bar but is not a valid url on its own. This is causing it to look for a file named Google.com in the current folder. Instead send `cn` as `http://google.com`

Comment: No idea why this whole thing is being downvoted, and i dont care much anymore, but thanks for this! It allowed me to move past this bug. +1

Comment: No worries, some idiots just down vote stuff because they dont like the question. Happy it helped.